# Table of comments structure

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, asp.net-mvc-4

I develop web-site. Database has many tables like **"News", "Blogs"** etc. So, I have to add comments functionality. Can you advice how I can realize that? Should I store comments for different tables into **single "Comment"** table and what is the structure of those table? Or should I create **multiple tables**, for example: **"News" -> "News_comments"**,
"Blogs" -> "Blogs_comments"?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One table only, with a column identifying the type of comment. Having multiple tables for the same purpose is just maintainace nightmare. One table is good enough.

Comment: So, You propose for example table with such fields: "comment_id", "type", "type_id", "text". Am I right?

Comment: Those columns looks fine. `comment_id, type, type_id` can all be int data types as well.

Comment: Why type and type_id? It should be only one which should be an int (corresponding to a ComentType enum)

Comment: And where should I store id of every blog post or news?

Comment: In a separate table. Your question was about comments and not about posts and news.

Answer (score 1):

In your case where you have separate table for categories such as New, Blogs etc its wise for you to have multiple table since the categories are hard coded tables.

The best would be to create two tables, one with having categories and another with comments, so you can have foreign key of the categories on the comment table.